# Is it possible to install Pascal compiler on a mac without installing XCODE?

Tags: macos, pascal, freepascal

I am looking for a way to install fpc or any other pascal compiler on my macbook without installing the 7gb Xcode because my internet sucks and I am a VIM guy. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe by downloading only the Command Line Tools ? On what "Tutorial" did you see that you needed XCode?

Comment: when I try to install fpc from the website the installers says that I need xcode to proceed, from where I can dowload the command line tools because I couldnt find it for my osx version (catarina), thanks

Comment: https://www.freepascal.org/download.html ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, it is!**

1. You need Homebrew

   - Installation of Homebrew is simple just paste this into your terminal:

```sh
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

2. You need to install **fpc**

   - Same case; Paste it into terminal.

```sh
brew install fpc
```

3. You can start to use **fpc**

Comment: as far as I remember it also needed XCode command line tools but they were qute small comparing to full XCode

Comment: @robertaleksic, I am like 99% sure, you did not. I actually tried it like 2 weeks ago. But maybe I am wrong.